# "OR" operator in Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, sql, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE in Java, I have a data table "Person" and I need doing something like:

`SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE NAME="MIKE" OR AGE=50`

My code builds "AND", I don't know how to build the sentence with OR

```
Query query = new Query(getEntityKind(), getRootEntityKey());
query.addFilter("name", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "Mike");
query.addFilter("age", FilterOperator.EQUAL, 50);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `OR` operator in GAE queries. The only way is to run two queries and then merge results.

Update: since 1.7.0, GAE supports `OR` queries via [`CompositeFilterOperator`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query.CompositeFilterOperator). What it does is basically run parallel queries and then AND/OR them on server. The cost is the same as running separate queries and merging them on client, but one saves on roundtrip times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do OR in JDO or JPA - but it's a bit of a trick because it actually translates your query into an IN query. That might give you some ideas on how to rewrite your query though.

Check out the end of this blog post for more: http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/queries-with-and-in-filters.html

Comment: `IN` query is performed on one property not on different properties. It also translates internally into a series of queries which merge results.